# Filter rows in a dataframe based on a partial match of one or more words

Tags: r

I would like to filter rows in a dataframe based on a partial match of one or more words in the query phrase with the phrases in the dataframe column cells. I tried the following for a start in vain.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

doc <- structure(list(LineNumber = structure(1:4, .Label = c("line 1", 
       "line 2", "line 3", "line 4"), class = "factor"), Statement = structure(c(2L, 
       1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Harry and Larry went down the hill", 
       "Jack and Jill went up the hill", "Jack fell down broke and broke his crown", 
       "Tom climbed up the hill"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("LineNumber", 
       "Statement"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

cmnWords <- c("the", "and", "for") # etc.

# need to replace the selected (or common words) from doc$Statement or making a copy of doc$Statement as  doc$Statement2 and filter the data frame 
# for example "Jack and Jill went up the hill" shall become "Jack Jill went up hill"
# then filtering the dataframe using the query string as a partial match

query <- "went up hill"

doc %>% filter(str_detect(Statement, query))

## The answer expected was the row that contained "Jack and Jill went up the hill" in doc$Statement2
```

Comment: Seems too broad. The parameters of the requirements for natural language parsing seem unspecified and potentially quite broad.

Comment: I am looking for something like ignoring the most common words and querying on less common words in the query against the data in the dataframe column. Is it possible? I was only looking for an advice on the strategy to proceed rather than a solution.Hence I kept the question broad. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I think I did understand. This is NOT (yet?) a question that is suitable for SO. Think of yourself as an analyst who needs to specify for a programming specialist a well-formed problem statement. You are not there yet. You need to think more concretely and present a set of inputs and output that will define whether the answer is adequate.

Comment: I think @mysteRious understood my query and provided a path forward that I was looking for.Not everybody understands problem unless too  explicit. I get it. I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to frame this as a text mining problem, but as the commenters stated above, this seems like a very broad and not well specified problem (the type of query you want to make, I believe, would be better suited by using a declarative programming language like Prolog). Regardless, here's how you might set it up in `tidytext` and chop out all the common words:

```
> library(tidytext)
> doc.t <- as.tibble(doc)
> doc.t$Statement <- as.character(doc.t$Statement)
> doc.t %>% unnest_tokens(word,Statement) %>% anti_join(stop_words)
Joining, by = "word"
# A tibble: 14 x 2
   LineNumber word   
   <fct>      <chr>  
 1 line 1     jack   
 2 line 1     jill   
 3 line 1     hill   
 4 line 2     harry  
 5 line 2     larry  
 6 line 2     hill   
 7 line 3     tom    
 8 line 3     climbed
 9 line 3     hill   
... the rest are truncated
```

The problem with eliminating the most common words is that it will also eliminate your ability to examine phrases like "went up the hill" where the sequence and ordering of the words is important.

Comment: Your suggestion gives me an idea on how to proceed further. Appreciate it.